# Linking a table to a pie chart and basing that chart on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to create a pie chart from the numbers in this table:

[image: This is some data]

But I first need to sort them into categories like this:

[image: Pie Chart]

It needs to be linked so the pie chart would update if the numbers change.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the specific use-case for [Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) and their very useful sibling [Pivot Charts](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/pivot-chart.html). I won't belabor the point too much here because it really is as simple as highlighting your table, going to `Insert -> PivotTable`. Move the fields in the `field list` on the right side of the window into the proper box (`Row` `Column` `Filter` `Values`). Within that table go to `Analyze -> Pivot Chart`.